# how to skip an item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I don't want to show an icon(image) in the ng-repeat item as it doesn't have proper image.I don't know the index of it but i know the name of the icon.
How can i do it.Here is my code below.

```
<ul class="assetList" style="padding-top:5px;">
    <li ng-repeat="partner in iconData.partners">
        <img title="{{partner.name}}" alt="" ng-src="{{imgSrc}}{{partner.icon}}" ng-style="{opacity:((jobDetails.partner.name == partner.name)) && '1' || partner.opacity}" style="opacity: {{opacity">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just hide it using [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide):

```
<img title="{{partner.name}}" ng-hide="partner.name=='theOneYouWantHidden'...
```

Comment: Click the up arrow and the checkmark next to my answer. :)  Here's a good post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work